# Get random numbers from lists that follow Poisson Distr

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution, monte-carlo

I have a simulation that produces each time a list of integers starting from `0` onwards

```
simulation 1: [0,1,2]
simulation 2: [0,1]
simulation 3: [0,1,2,3,4,5]
etc..
```

I want to choose one element each time so that

1. I can get a target mean (example `1.45`)
2. The sampled numbers follow a **poisson distribution**.

I have tried generating those lists using a poisson distribution with a specific mean (example 9.5) and the meaning of those lists is how many times number 3 can fit as a whole inside.
So sampling poisson(9.5) I may get

```
simulation 1: 8 -> the max number of 3s is 2, hence choose one of these:[0,1,2]
simulation 2: 3 -> the max number of 3s is 1, hence choose one of these:[0,1]
simulation 3: 16-> the max number of 3s is 5, hence choose one of these:[0,1,2,3,4,5]
...
```

Then my goal is to say my target 3s mean is  1.45 for example and

```
1. from simulation 1 chose 0
2. from simulation 2 chose 2
3. from simulation 3 chose 1
etc...
```

**What I tried:**
Split each simulation in N-1 spaces using the Poisson(1.45) CDF

```
prob 0: (0, 0.2345)
prob 1: (0.2345, 0.5745)
....
prob n: (poisson(n-1, 1.45), 1)
```

and choose based on those probs, but my method fails. I do not get the expected mean, and even if I do, my distribution is not poisson.

Comment: You must select $k=0,1,2,\dotsc$ from the simulated lists at the same theoretical frequencies of the Poisson distribution. This will be impossible if certain numbers are not repeated enough in the simulated lists. If your intention is just to simulate a Poisson RV you should do it in a more conventional method. Otherwise, you might want to add more context about what these simulations mean, and why you want to select numbers from them that, hopefully, follow a Poisson distribution in their frequency of occurrence.